# core data naive question

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, core-data

to create entity I use

```
studys *temppatient = (studys *)[NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"studys" inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext_NEW];
```

what if I waant to create object of the entity to use it as temp , what's the proper code to create object of entity

Answer (score 0):

I'd do it this way:

```
NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Studies" 
                                          inManagedObjectContext:myManagedObjectContext];

Studies *studies = [[Studies alloc] initWithEntity:entity   
                    insertIntoManagedObjectContext:myManagedObjectContext];
```

`Studies` is a subclass of the NSManagedObject class. You can create it automatically by selecting your entity and create it with:

*File -> New File -> Cocoa Touch Class -> Managed Object Class*.

Comment: what's QuestionWithAnswers I just need an object from studies entity

Comment: @AMH sorry that didn't belong there, adapted some code of mine for your example. Corrected it.

Comment: I don't want to use it for insertion, I want it as temp

Comment: I do migration, transfer data from sqlite file to another , to solve the different context problem I use it as temp for transfer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6100812/illegal-attempt-to-establish-a-relationship-between-objects-in-different-contexts

Comment: As temp object it doesnt have to be a coredata object

Comment: @AMH as far as I understand the managed object: You simply can't have an independent instance of a manahed object, that's why it is called managed. Here's a quote from aplles doc: `"If you instantiate a managed object directly, you must call the designated initializer (initWithEntity:insertIntoManagedObjectContext:)"`

Comment: so could u help me in this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6100812/illegal-attempt-to-establish-a-relationship-between-objects-in-different-contexts

Comment: will the code u gave to me will insert new record in the database

Comment: @AMH yes it will insert a new managed object in the managed object you provided, however like in your other question you cannot simply move a managed object from one context to other like TechZen stated.

Comment: to transfer data from on sqllite database to another

Comment: @AMH do you need two databases? Or do you just want to move to a newer version of your first database?

Comment: I need to move to new version , but I didn't set versioning from the beginning , so I created new one and want to transfer data to it

Answer (score 0):

You can insert entities on a nil context and add them to a valid context later on....

I have sample code and a full write-up.... [Temporary Storage In CoreData](http://www.locassa.com/index.php/2011/05/temporary-storage-in-apples-coredata/)

Comment: u mean studys *temppatient = (studys *)[NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"studys" inManagedObjectContext:nil]; and use it as temp ccould u help me in this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6100812/illegal-attempt-to-establish-a-relationship-between-objects-in-different-contexts

Comment: Take a look at the blog post I linked, it has code examples and you can download the project and see it working. The basic idea is to alloc / init the 'studys' object directly rather than go through NSEntityDescription.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use it as temp simply delete it from the context before saving the context. That's what I would do in this case. I have used this technique extensively when synching core data contents from web services. So init your entity in your context. Set your properties or whatever. Use the object to transfer the properties to another managed object and remove the temp entity from the context before saving the context. That should do.

Comment: Lets say you have two managed objects: object1 and object2. The first is one you fetched from your context. The second is a newly created object that you have just inserted in the same context. You set the props of object 2 to whatever data you have and use it as a temporary object. When you're done you can set whatever property you need from object2 to object1 with setters and then do a [managedObjectContext deleteObject:object2]; before actually saving the context state (including the modified object1) with a [managedObjectContext save:&saveError]; call